# Get value from JSON and put it in String

Tags: java, android, json

it's my first question here, i've try to be the more explicit :)

I want get value from a `JSON` page : https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x3p6d9r?fields=onair.

I have follow a tutorial about `json object`.

But i want get the value `"onair"` and put this in a `String` for use a `IF STRING == "XX"`.

This is my code :

```
public class notification extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);

        detectonline();

    }

    public void detectonline(){
        /*
        if (xx == "false") {
             Do something is live is off
        }
        else{
           Do something is live is on
        }

         */

    }

    public static boolean checkIfOnline(String channel) throws IOException {
        String channerUrl = "https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x3p6d9r?fields=onair";

        String jsonText = readFromUrl(channerUrl);// reads text from URL

        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject json = parser.parse(jsonText).getAsJsonObject();

        return !json.get("onair").isJsonNull();
    }

    private static String readFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {
        URL page = new URL(url);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Scanner scanner = null;
        try{
            //scanner = new Scanner(page.openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
            scanner = new Scanner(page.openStream());
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
                sb.append(scanner.nextLine());
            }
        }finally{
            if (scanner!=null)
                scanner.close();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remake your method according what you are looking for it's one of several way to parse json data :

```
 public static boolean checkIfOnline(String channel) throws JSONException, IOException {
    String channerUrl = "https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x3p6d9r?fields=onair";

    String jsonText = readFromUrl(channerUrl);// reads text from URL

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText); // You create a json object from your string jsonText
    if(json.has("onair")) { // just a simple test to check the node that you need existe
        boolean value = json.getBoolean("onair"); // In the url that you gave onair value is boolean type 
        return value;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help, but i have an error on `String jsonText = readFromUrl(channerUrl);// reads text from URL`. I have a error : `Unhandled exception: java.io.IOexception`

Comment: then just wrap the statement with a try catch block

Comment: Change the method like this : public static boolean checkIfOnline(String channel) throws JSONException , IOException

Answer (score 0):

I will create methode using your way  !

```
public static boolean checkIfOnline(String channel) throws IOException {
        String channerUrl = "https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x3p6d9r?fields=onair";

        String jsonText = readFromUrl(channerUrl);// reads text from URL

        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();


      String myString =json.get("onair");
 return mystring;}
```